# How to convert certain time in IST timezone to that of north-virginia time

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
11-10-2016 11:31:51 // Is in IST
```

I want to convert the above time to its equivalent time in north-virginia as my AWS server is set up to north virginia.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a module called moment.js to convert between timezones.You can find more information about it here http://momentjs.com/